# Паспорт на образец или паспорт образца?

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология

Как правильно: паспорт на образец или паспорт образца?

Есть некий образец, и на него выдают паспорт, сертификат соответствия, иначе говоря.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, это ваш случай:

[Паспорт на изделие](http://c-kd.ru/uslugi/pasport-izdeliya) — это вид конструкторской или технической документации, в которой содержатся технические и эксплуатационные характеристики изделия или же оборудования

Answer (score 0):

**Паспорт образца...**

Например, паспорт образца 19ХХ года, паспорт старого/нового образца.

Comment: Но "паспорт образца" подразумевает форму этого паспорта... А в данном случае есть некий образец и на него выдают паспорт, сертификат соответствия, иначе говоря...

Comment: Паспорт по образцу?